# backup/restore/DR scenario for Azure single instance VM?

Tags: virtual-machines, azure

I currently have a single instance azure VM with one OS disk and one data disk.  I'm running it with a reserved public IP.

Adding a 2nd VM in an availability set isn't an option as I'm hosting an off the shelf software package that doesn't lend itself to that architecture.

I can take a bit of downtime - i don't need high availability however I want an optimized restore process.

Every week I run a powershell script that takes the VM down, and snapshots the OS and data disks with a timestamp. I have a different process to backup actual data.

In the event that the VM fails or becomes corrupted  (Azure VM random reboots anyone?), I'm leaning towards two scenarios

1. delete the VM and create a new VM using the same reserved IP (will it let me?) and attach os and data disks from a previous snapshot.

OR

2. create a deprovisioned mirror VM image with a different reserved IP.  in the event of a failure, i bring it online and attach os and data disks from a previous snapshot.  Then I change DNS to route to the new machine.

OR would it be possible to keep a deprovisioned VM at all times with a previous set of disks attached using the same reserved IP - that way if the main primary VM goes down, I can just bring this one up and be on my way?

Comment: What Operating System and App Software are you running - this will feed into the best way to recover from a failure.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options to do this. I may do the following:

Create a new VM, make sure you reserve an IP (at the time of VM creation), and switch off the VM (deallocate or not deallocated). Consider this as your secondary (backup) machine. Once when your primary fails, you can de-link the disks associated there and attach the same here and power on. This will make your tasks simpler.

Stopped and deallocated will not incur you the VM cost, whereas stopped, but not deallocated will incur you VM cost. This is described [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-azure/vm-shutdown-types-windows-azure).

Answer (score 0):

Azure now has a feature where you can directly backup an Azure VM without any downtime - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-vms-prepare/

Comment: But that backup would exist where? I would assume you'd want to have another instance of a VM running in another region to be on the safe side, no?

Comment: That backup would exist as a backup file in your backup vault. It would be in the same region as the original.  If you wanted to be protected against regional outages, yes, you'd need to run services in different regions and use Traffic Manager to load balance across them, etc.